# Get method on hashtable that contains long values

Tags: java, hashtable

I have a hashtable that I have declared as:
`Hashtable<Long, Long> sumhash = new Hashtable<Long, Long>();`
Now, when I check if there exists a key using:

```
if(sumhash.containsKey(diff) == true){
    start = sumhash.get(diff);
} //diff contains a Long value.
```

It works when I am checking if `diff` exists in the hashtable or not but when I am trying to get vaule using the `get()` method, It gives me `error: incompatible types: Long cannot be converted to int`

I am new to Java, Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type is `start`? Is it an `int` even thou you have `Long` objects in your `Hashtable`?

Comment: Is this line of your code causing the error? `start = sumhash.get(diff);`

Comment: You could cast to int `start = (int) sumhash.get(diff);`

Comment: @MadyDaby, that change it to did not work out. But it was something I did not try. Also,  yes it is int but why am I not able to cast float into an int?

Comment: btw @Progman your solution worked out thanks, but still, why does casting not work here?

Comment: @BATMAN I'm not sure, but you could try [`Math.toIntExact(sumhash.get(diff));`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toIntExact-long-) as an alternative to cast.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast it with .intValue().
The issue here is that in the hash table you are storing the values as Long objects and thus you need a bit more than just parenthesis to cast. Here is a more comprehensive explanation: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-long-to-int